# rails4 get from omniauth user link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

How to get user url from omniauth.hash? If user authorize with social(twitter, facebook, vk, etc.) I want to take link to their profile and put it on the page as link.

I use omniauth-facebook(and others) at rails 4. My config in `initializers/devise.rb` is simple:

```
  config.omniauth :vkontakte, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'
  config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'
  config.omniauth :twitter, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'
```

With this config I have very poor auth.hash on callback, in yml it looks so:

```
provider: facebook
uid: '***************'
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  email: ****************
  name: ****************
  image: ************************
credentials: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  token: ****************
  expires_at: ******
  expires: *****
extra: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    name: ****************
    email: ******************
    id: '*******************'
```

I put `*` instead real values,  here no user url. According to https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook (scroll to the bottom) it should be: request.env['auth.hash'].extra.row_info.link or .info.urls.Facebook

How to get url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this configuration](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring):

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', info_fields: 'name,email,link'
```

Don't forget to restart the application.